# How to find out which process eats up CPU?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, eclipse-rcp

I have an eclipse RCP application, which, after some reproducible events occur eats up 100 % of CPU.

I can connect to it from another Eclpse instance in debug mode.

Does the Eclipse debugger allow to find out where exactly the problem is (what thread consumes the CPU power) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find problematic thread in Eclipse remote debugger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362107/how-to-find-problematic-thread-in-eclipse-remote-debugger)

Comment: The question title doesn't match the question. Do you want to find a process or the thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No but you can use one of those free tools:

- [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)
- [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html)

Both tools are included in the recent SDKs. You find them in the bin folder as `jvisualvm.exe` and `jmc.exe`. I used VisualVM a lot and really like it, JMC came first with JDK 7 Update 40 and I haven't used it yet.